# actionscript 3 security class import

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, network-programming, cross-domain-policy

So affter just getting a (my first) working server up, (nothing big or impressive yet, kinof useless without the client eh?) and testing it with a whip-together C++ client, the next step is to make a connection from what is going to be its long-term mate (once completeing, still a WIP).

The sever side is in C++ and client side in AS3, and long story short, i cant find what import.* i need for the security calls to fetch the policy file from the server. Im working in FlashDevelop FYI.

i need the function: Security.loadPolicyFile();

any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Cheers;
-Tyler

Answer (score 0):

well after some moe digging i found the import i was looking for,   import flash.system.Security; seemed rather hard to find but its all working now.